# How to get data from controller to view using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-3

View:

```
<select class="form-control" id="emp_id" name="emp_id">
<option value="">--- Select Emp id ---</option>
  <?php foreach($employee as $emp){?>
     <option value="<?php echo $emp->id;?>"><?php echo $emp->id;?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
<div id="home"></div>

<script>
$('select[name="emp_id"]').on('change', function() {
var id=$("#emp_id").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/employee_master"+id,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
      alert("hi");
      console.log(data.res);
    },
    error: function( error )
    {
        alert( error );
    }
});
   return false;
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function employee_master($id)
{
    $data['res']=$this->payslip_model->fetch_employee_name($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function fetch_employee_name($id)
{
   $this->db->select('name');
   $this->db->from('employee_master');
   $this->db->where('id',$id);
   $res=$this->db->get();
   return $res->result();
}
```

In above code,I am using dataType:'json' in ajax, it will always execute error function in ajax.If I am not using dataType:'json' it works fine, but I cannot know how to retrieve the data from controller to ajax.Please help me to find out the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it will give you error when you use data type json. it means that on ajax call the data will be pass to controller in json format.. 
while you are passing a simple post data...

remove the datatype json. every thing is ok...

and more mistake use this line

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/contorller_name/employee_master/"+id,
```

Comment: Ok..Then how can I retrieve the data from controller

Comment: write the actual problem which you have face.

Comment: what is the return of success: function(data) {
      alert("hi");
      console.log(data);
    },

Comment: emp name need to be display in success function

Comment: show the json object which is return in success function console.log(data) ?

Comment: If I am using json it will execute error function in ajax so that I am not using dataType:'json' now execute success function console.log(data.res), but it display undefined

Comment: write console.log(data) ... it will show the json object

Comment: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'</p>
<p>Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 532</p>


 <p>Backtrace:</p>
 
  
 
  
 
  
 
  
   <p style="margin-left:10px">
   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\star\index.php<br />
   Line: 315<br />
   Function: require_once   </p>
</div> it displays error like that in console

Comment: put your controller name in the following line

Comment: url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controller_name/employee_master/"+id,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174268/discussion-between-zarif-khan-and-sridhar).